# AngularFire2 causing infinite loops in iOS browsers

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I'm having a bit of a unique issue and I have been going crazy trying to solve it.

I have an Angular2 app using WebPack with AngularFire2 to manipulate meta data. The current feature I'm working on is the ability to upload a file to Firebase Storage, obtaining the URL for that location, then attaching that url to the meta data of the object the file was uploaded to for the user to view if wanted. This works as wanted in all desktop and android browsers, but fails on almost all iOS browsers (tested on Safari, Chrome, Firefox, all same results) with 0 console or system errors, simply refuses any more operations on the site, can't reload, unable to do anything but force close the tab or the browser app and reload.

Here's a breakdown of my code:

This is the HTML that loops through the `FirebaseListObservable` and displays the data in the view:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="{{ item.$key }}" class="inputfile" (change)="uploadPicture($event, item)"/>
    <label [attr.for]="item.$key">{{item.name}}</label>
    <img *ngIf="item.fileUrl" src="../../assets/img/star.png" class="cell-img" (click)=showImg(item.fileUrl)>
</div>
```

Uploading the file:

```
firebase.storage().ref().child('images/' + filename).put(file, metadata).then(snapshot => this.obtainUploadUrl(snapshot, key, filename));
```

After obtaining the file location url, and passing on the firebase object key (which sits in a FirebaseListObservable), I update the list like so:

```
console.log("Updating", key, "With", data);
this.af.database.list('/games/' + this.currentGame.$key + '/items').update(key, data);
```

To the best of my knowledge the failure occurs anywhere I manipulate the `items` list or the local `this.items` after obtaining the snapshot for the file upload. When I try to update, push, or remove any object in that `FirebaseListObservable` the mobile site stops working and gets stuck in some infinite loop.

There has to be some special case I'm not accounting for or some misuse of the Firebase objects that iOS isn't happy with me using.

Any help at all is appreciated, I can't seem to find any solution but to not use Firebase.

**UPDATE**

After another day of hacking away at it, I have found that firebase, within an iOS browser, does not like updating view items within, at least, an input click function.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="{{ item.$key }}" class="inputfile" (change)="uploadPicture($event, item, items)"/>
```

Inside that uploadPicture function, if I run two lines of code:

```
firebase.storage().ref().child('images/' + filename).put(file, metadata).then(snapshot => console.log("File uploaded!", snapshot));
this.items.update(key, {fileName: filename});
```

I get the same error in iOS. However, if I try to alter any other firebase object it won't freeze on me. Still not sure why this fails for just iOS right now though, and I still have no clue how to solve this problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the issue was that iOS refused to let me upload a file and alter the firebase object through the same function. Any firebase action taken on the iterated objects through a function starting at the input HTML tag would stall the website. Eventually I simply had to do a two step process, one where I staged the file and loaded it into memory, and a second stage that would upload it and update the firebase objects.

Fun times.